# How do I restore new shortcut to Windows 11 explorer right-click context menu?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I have Windows 11 Pro 21H2 build 22000.795. Two months ago all items in the "new" context menu for Windows Explorer disappeared. Searching and finding a solution I did a registry tweak to restore them. Last week I noticed the new shortcut item missing and apparently did not restore with the registry tweak. What I needed at the time was new text document which I use all the time and assumed everything else restored.

From another Windows machine I compared hcr\file, hcr\folder, hklm\software\classes\file, hklm\software\classes\folder. These are the same. I also compared hkcu values. Because these are the same and because the new shortcut context menu item does not appear for any user, probably the DLL responsible for that needs registering again. Can someone tell me what DLL? Any other thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: What “registry tweak” exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer at https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/24412-add-remove-default-new-context-menu-items-windows-10-a.html

Login as admin and open this reg file or run regedt32 as admin and import. When comparing to the other machine I should have compared hkcr/.lnk .

```
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew]
"Handler"="{ceefea1b-3e29-4ef1-b34c-fec79c4f70af}"
"IconPath"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
  00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,\
  31,00,36,00,37,00,36,00,39,00,00,00
"ItemName"="@shell32.dll,-30397"
"MenuText"="@shell32.dll,-30318"
"NullFile"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew\Config]
"DontRename"=""
```